# Parsing binary files in C++

Tags: c++, binary-data

I'm trying to read a binary format using C++
For some reason I'm able to parse only the first variable.
The header sequence is:
[2 byte integer][1 byte integer][1byte integer]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct HDR {
unsigned short int signature;
unsigned char version;
unsigned char tricnt;
} header;

int main(){
    ifstream infile("1.mdl",ios::in | ios::binary);
    if(!infile){
        cout<<"Error\n";
        return 1;
    }
    infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&header),sizeof(HDR));
    cout<<"SIG "<<header.signature<<endl;
    cout<<"VER "<<header.version<<endl;

    cout<<"TRI "<<header.tricnt<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason I'm able to parse only the signature, the rest of the structure is empty.

Comment: Are you sure that those variables aren't zero in the actual file?

Comment: It might be a structure packing/alignment issue. What's your compiler?

Comment: You're making a dangerous assumption with your usage of `sizeof(HDR)` -- the compiler is allowed to add padding between the structure fields, so the structure layout may not match the file layout.

Comment: The variables are not zero since I created the binary file in the first place. The compilerI'm using is gcc that comes with os x 10.7

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have specific knowledge of the padding used by your implementation you should read into the members individually.

```
infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&header.signature), sizeof header.signature);
infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&header.version), sizeof header.version);
infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&header.tricnt), sizeof header.tricnt);
```

Of course, you are still relying on `unsigned short` being 2 bytes on your platform and the representation in the file having the same endianness as your machine but at least you aren't making assumptions about structure padding.

Naturally, when you're printing `unsigned char` the character represented will be printed. If you want to see the numeric value you should cast to a non-`char` integer type. ASCII 1 (start of header) and 3 (end of text) are control characters and not usually visible when printed.

```
cout<<"VER "<< static_cast<int>(header.version) <<endl;
cout<<"TRI "<< static_cast<int>(header.tricnt) <<endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the info I'll try it. The types are just for the example.

Comment: Tried it using GCC 4.4.1 on ubuntu. Still the same problem.

Comment: What are the first four bytes of your file and what tool have you used to verify them?

Comment: I've created the file using a python script. I've tried to read the data from python and it is excatly what was writen. The first 4 bytes are: 19 83 01 03

Comment: Are what you've writted hex bytes?

Comment: @KianTern: I verified your program using your 4 byte test file and `./a.out | hexdump -C` . It gave the "correct" output on my system.

Comment: Solved: it was a problem with cout LOL. Thanks

Comment: @KianTern: Really, what was the problem with `cout`? You should post an answer if the solution could potentially help someone else.

Comment: I forgot I need to cast char to int in cout  call